# For loop is not doing the next part or something is wrong with my function VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, function, printing

working on a roman numeral calculator (still learning, so if this is a easy fix don't judge :P)

The problem I am having is that when seeing if i can read the values from the array in my function (arr_rnnum) using Debug.print the first value gets read fine but the second value always returns a zero. I tried adding the count j = j + 1 in the for loop but that is having no effect

For example if I change the debug.print to getting_values(0) and in the inputbox enter X,V it will print 10 but if I change it to debug.print to getting_values(1) it prints 0

If anyone can see what the problem is it would be a great help

### Here is my code

```
Public Sub main()
   Debug.Print getting_values(1)
End Sub
```

---

```
Function getting_values()    
   Dim arr_rnstr() As String
   Dim rnstr As String
   Dim arr_rnnum() As Integer

   rnstr = InputBox("enter the roman numeral in descending order of value and put a comma between each")
   arr_rnstr() = Split(rnstr, ",") 'splits the string the user entered into single values'
   ReDim arr_rnnum(UBound(arr_rnstr)) 'sets the size of the array of numbers to the upper bound of the array of letter the user entered'
   For j = LBound(arr_rnstr) To UBound(arr_rnstr) 'this section checks each value of the array of letters and replaces it with a number in a second array'
      Select Case arr_rnstr(j)
         Case Is = "I"
            arr_rnnum(j) = 1
         Case Is = "V"
            arr_rnnum(j) = 5
         Case Is = "X"
            arr_rnnum(j) = 10
         Case Is = "L"
            arr_rnnum(j) = 50
         Case Is = "C"
            arr_rnnum(j) = 100
         Case Is = "D"
            arr_rnnum(j) = 500
         Case Is = "M"
            arr_rnnum(j) = 1000
      End Select
      j = j + 1
   Next j
   getting_values = arr_rnnum
End Function
```

Comment: I don't see a parameter in your function/method `getting_values` as written.. I don't see a param arg usage either.. so what is the 0 and/or 1 supposed to represent?

try `getting_values()(1)` for that would be a method call, followed by the index of the returned array.. I think.. I am not so strong in VBA

Comment: @Brett thanks for the reply but i don't understand what you mean when you said you don't see a parameter as written or a param arg (only started coding two weeks ago). The 0 and 1 are meant to represent the first and second values in the `arr_rnnum` array. I tried `getting_values()(1)` but it didn't work

Comment: roger. but it isn't going to be an array type until the method is actually called.. so `getting_values(0)` **is not** **getting** the `0` index of the resulting array, it's **calling** the method and passing it a value of `0` or `false`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is you need to complete the method call before using the resulting array..

**change**

```
Debug.Print getting_values(1)
```

**to**

```
Debug.Print getting_values()(1)
```

The values `0` and `1` that you are currently calling `getting_values` method with represent `false` and `true`, respectfully.

I don't particular know why passing `false` in your method call is allowing `Debug Print` to display the first value of the resulting array.

---

```
Public Sub main()
   Debug.Print getting_values()(1)
End Sub

Function getting_values() As Integer()
    Dim arr_rnstr() As String
    Dim rnstr As String
    Dim arr_rnnum() As Integer

    rnstr = InputBox("enter the roman numeral in descending order of value and put a comma between each")
    ' split the string the user entered into single values
    arr_rnstr() = Split(rnstr, ",") 

    ' set the size of the array of numbers to the upper bound of the array of letter the user entered
    ReDim arr_rnnum(UBound(arr_rnstr)) 

    ' checks each value of the array of letters and replaces it with a number in a second array
    For index = LBound(arr_rnstr) To UBound(arr_rnstr) Step 1           
        Select Case arr_rnstr(index)
            Case Is = "I"
                arr_rnnum(index) = 1
            Case Is = "V"
                arr_rnnum(index) = 5
            Case Is = "X"
                arr_rnnum(index) = 10
            Case Is = "L"
                arr_rnnum(index) = 50
            Case Is = "C"
                arr_rnnum(index) = 100
            Case Is = "D"
                arr_rnnum(index) = 500
            Case Is = "M"
                arr_rnnum(index) = 1000
        End Select
    Loop
    getting_values = arr_rnnum
End Function
```

Comment: just tried it again when using X,V `Debug.Print getting_values()(0)` it still returns the first value (10) but when `Debug.Print getting_values()(1)` it returns 0 (should be 5)

Comment: `getting_values()(0)` should be returning the first (zero) index of the resulting array... as expected.. ensure you are seperating your input with the commas; ensure you **remove** the `j = j + 1` line.. go ahead and specify the step in the for loop as well `For j = LBound(arr_rnstr) To UBound(arr_rnstr) Step 1`

Comment: Last, but certainly not least, be **Explicit** with your function return types.. declare the function with the return type of integer()

Answer (score 0):

I think I have fix your problem, You can not return the array as such because it does not return any thing. Store to a string and return it , so that it will be easier.

```
Public Sub main()
   Debug.Print getting_values()
End Sub


Function getting_values()
   Dim arr_rnstr() As String
   Dim rnstr As String
   Dim arr_rnnum() As Integer
   Dim arr_num(12) As String
   Dim rn As String

   rnstr = InputBox("enter the roman numeral in descending order of value and put a comma between each")
   arr_rnstr() = Split(rnstr, ",") 'splits the string the user entered into single values'
   ReDim arr_rnnum(UBound(arr_rnstr)) 'sets the size of the array of numbers to the upper bound of the array of letter the user entered'
   For j = LBound(arr_rnstr) To UBound(arr_rnstr) 'this section checks each value of the array of letters and replaces it with a number in a second array'
      Select Case arr_rnstr(j)
         Case Is = "I"
              arr_num(j) = 1
         Case Is = "V"
              arr_num(j) = 5
         Case Is = "X"
              arr_num(j) = 10
         Case Is = "L"
              arr_num(j) = 50
         Case Is = "C"
              arr_num(j) = 100
         Case Is = "D"
              arr_num(j) = 500
         Case Is = "M"
              arr_num(j) = 1000
      End Select
      rn = rn + arr_num(j) + " "
   Next j
   getting_values = rn
End Function
```